# QTableView отрисовка данных

Tags: qt, c++

Так как кода много, скину кусочек) Делаю следующее. Написал свою модель от QAbstractTableModel. Привязал к QTableView. По таймеру (0.5 сек) обновляю список процессов и заношу в таблицу, при этом вычисляя разницу между предыдущем и обновленным списком процессов и, в соответсвии с этой разницей, добавляю или удаляю строки в таблице, а затем перезаписываю данные. Проблема в следующем: при отображении таблицы, данные никак не меняются. Однако, если выделить строку или проскроллить таблицу туда-сюда, то они обновляются... Какая-то проблема с отрисовкой что-ли) Как это исправить? Заранее благодарен)

```
void ProcessMonitor::updateProcessList()
{
    QDir *dir = new QDir("/proc");
    QStringList dirProcessList = dir->entryList(QStringList("*"), QDir::AllDirs);
    QFile stat;

    int len = processList.size();

    processList.clear();
    foreach(QString str, dirProcessList)
    {
        if (str.toInt())
        {
            stat.setFileName("/proc/" + str.toUtf8() + "/stat");
            stat.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);

            processList.append(getProcessInfoByStat(&stat));

            stat.close();
        }
        else continue;
    }

    int dif = len - processList.size();

    if (dif < 0)
    {
        processTableModel->insertRows(0, -dif, QModelIndex());
    }
    else if (dif > 0)
    {
        processTableModel->removeRows(0,  dif, QModelIndex());
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < processList.size(); i++)
    {
        processTableModel->setData(processTableModel->index(i, 0), processList.at(i)->comm,  Qt::DisplayRole);
        processTableModel->setData(processTableModel->index(i, 1), processList.at(i)->pid,   Qt::DisplayRole);
        processTableModel->setData(processTableModel->index(i, 2), processList.at(i)->stat,  Qt::DisplayRole);
        processTableModel->setData(processTableModel->index(i, 3), processList.at(i)->nice,  Qt::DisplayRole);
        processTableModel->setData(processTableModel->index(i, 4), processList.at(i)->cpu,   Qt::DisplayRole);
        processTableModel->setData(processTableModel->index(i, 5), processList.at(i)->stime, Qt::DisplayRole);
    }

    sort();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Доброго времени суток!

По тому участку кода, который Вы предоставили сложно судить в чем именно проблема. Однако есть сразу несколько мест, где может быть допущена ошибка. Суть их сводится примерно к одному: **вид** (т.е. QTableView или его наследник) **никак не уведомляется об изменениях произошедших в модели**.

1) Реализация setData() в Вашей модели. В документации Qt по данной функции сказано:

> The dataChanged() signal should be
> emitted if the data was successfully
> set.

Проверьте испускает ли Ваша модель сигнал `dataChanged()` при успешном изменении элемента модели.

2) Реализация insertRows() по умолчанию ничего не делает согласно документации Qt:

> Note: The base class implementation of
> this function does nothing and returns
> false.

Если же вы перекрыли реализацию `insertRows()` проверьте, что внутри ее реализации есть вызовы `beginInsertRows()` и `endInsertRows()`, опять же согласно документации:

> If you implement your own model, you
> can reimplement this function if you
> want to support insertions.
> Alternatively, you can provide your
> own API for altering the data. In
> either case, you will need to call
> beginInsertRows() and endInsertRows()
> to notify other components that the
> model has changed.

Желаю успехов!

P.S. "Если ничего не получается - прочтите, наконец, инструкцию" (с) народная мудрость ))

Comment: Спасибо большое) Проблема была в dataChanged(). Впредь постараюсь следовать народной мудрости ;)

Comment: Пометьте ответ как правильный)